# why does this keep looping? despite me updating the appropriate variables

Tags: python, while-loop

I reviewed this code many, many times but I can't figure out what the hell is wrong?
this code is supposed to ask for user input (price of house, annual salary, semi-annual raise, number of months you're willing to wait to buy a house) then  outputs what the best savings rate is to hit the target number of months. also savings gain interest at a 4% rate. A bisection search is used.

```
print('what is the cost of your dream home?')
total_cost=float(input())
print ('what is your annual salary?')
annual_salary=float(input())
portion_down_payment=0.25*total_cost
current_savings=0
print('enter a semi-annual raise, as a decimal')
semi_annual_raise=float(input())

print('in how mnay months do you want to buy your house?')
target_months = int(input())

number_of_months=0
saving_rate=0
first=0
last=10000
steps_in_bisection=0

while target_months != number_of_months:
    saving_rate= int((first+last)/2)
    print ('ok')
    print(number_of_months)
    current_savings=0
    number_of_months=0
    while current_savings < portion_down_payment or current_savings-100< portion_down_payment :
        current_savings += ((saving_rate/10000)*(annual_salary/12))+ (current_savings*0.04)/12
        number_of_months=1+number_of_months
        if number_of_months %6 == 0:
            annual_salary+= semi_annual_raise * annual_salary
       
    
    if number_of_months>target_months:
        first=saving_rate
        steps_in_bisection+=1
        print ('here')
        print(number_of_months)
    elif number_of_months<target_months:
        last=saving_rate
        steps_in_bisection+=1
        print('there') 
        print(number_of_months)
print("best savings rate: ", saving_rate)




print("number of months:",number_of_months)
```

Comment: Which `while` loop specifically, and what debugging have you done? A loop will only continue if the condition is true, so you should double check the values being used in the condition.

Comment: Honestly, I've never understood the order that operations are done in. Fill the thing up with brackets so it's absolutely clear to everyone (including the computer).

Comment: @Pam While explicit grouping can be used for readability purposes, you can lookup [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) so you know the execution order for sure. The operators at the top of the chart are evaluated first.

Comment: It looks quite possible in your code for `number_of_months` to go *past* `target_months`, which will give you an infinite loop.

Comment: One of your problems is that you keep setting `number_of_months` to 0 *within the loop*. That means the outer loop is unlikely to ever complete because `number_of_months` only takes on the values 0 and 1 while `target_months` could be any user-inputted value.

Comment: Suggest you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Break your code into functions, which you can then test one as a time. It is much easier to find a problem in sort piece of code than is a long one.

For example, make inner loop a function, then make outer loop a function, which will call the inner loop.

2. Your outer loop's condition is for inequality:

   ```
   while target_months != number_of_months:
   ```

There are two problems: If the values are not integers, it can happen, you have values that are very similar, but not quite equal, for example: 1.0000001 and 1.

Or, the number might skip that exact value:

```
x = 5
while x != 0:
    x = x - 2
```

In this segment, values of x will be: 5, 3, 1, -1, -3, -5, ... but never 0, so the look will go forever.

3. You set the value `number_of_months=0` inside the loop which tests its value (the outer loop)
4. The value for `last` is arbitrarily set to 10000. Is it possible it's too small? Should it depend on the values of inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I finally figured it out guys.
annual_salary should be set back to its orginal user input value before the start of the second while loop. Otherwise anuual_salary will keep on increasing by the semi annual raise amount and therefore, lower and lower savings rate would be accepted as annual salary keeps rising.

Comment: If you make the inner loop a separate function, then you'd have a local variable annual_salary inside this function changing value -- which wouldn't affect the annual_salary in the outer loop.